# custom bib style, book output with pages numbers ex. 522pp

Tags: bibtex

This is my first post, after I have been looking for a while at the related posts without success. I'm using `TeXworks` (0.4.3 r.857 `MikTeX` 2.9 64bits) on Windows. 
Well, I have modified an existing style from the Canadian Journal of Aquatic and Fisheries Science (`cjafs.bst`) to fit [Fisheries Oceanography requirements](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291365-2419/homepage/ForAuthors.html)
the journal ask for book references like this:

```
Kawasaki, T. (1982) Pelagic Fish Stocks. Tokyo: Koseisha-Koseikaku, 327pp. (In Japanese).
```

Until now I just managed to get it like this:

```
Kawasaki, T. (1982) Pelagic Fish Stocks. Koseisha-Koseikaku.p.327.
```

I need to add the `city adress={}` follow by colon, then publishers and a comma, and finally pages (`field pages={}`) like the example **number**pp...
how can I do that, modifying the FUNCTION {book}?

```
    FUNCTION {book}
    { output.bibitem
     author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
     if$
     }
     if$
      format.date "year" output.check
      date.block
      format.btitle "title" output.check
      crossref missing$
     { format.bvolume output
       new.block
       format.number.series output
       new.sentence
       format.publisher.address output
       }
       {
       new.block
       format.book.crossref output.nonnull
       }
       if$
       format.edition output
       format.doi output
       new.block
       format.note output
       new.block            %just added number pages
       format.pages output  %just added number pages
       fin.entry
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I was curious.